# iframe embedding in page

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, css-float

I have an iframe page at http://kuroato.com/apo/adplay.html and I want to embed this iframe in http://kuroato.com/apo/iframe.html is same directory but whenever I try to add it using

```
<iframe src="adplay.html" height="700" width="800" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" alt="" title=" "/></iframe>
```

It just goes right aligned in that div box...only half left part remains visible.

My adplay.html is using style.css and iframe.html is using iframe.css files.

Just help me...I want it to add itself dynamically according to the div window size.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a #gameBox css-rule, that contain a "margin-right:100px" (thats why it is left-aligned). 
If you remove "margin-right:100px" the iframe will become centered

For the dynamic width, you use 100% instead of 800px, to get the div size.

Hope this help. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set the alignment of the iframe in platform.html you need to wrap the iframe in a div or a placeholder and set the alignment some thing like

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:100%;text-align:right"><iframe src="eclipse.html"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

let me know if it helps

Comment: in my screen i see it left aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot exactly see what you're trying to describe, but it seems to be a CSS issue.
First of all, you've got a `height="700" width="800"` in your iframe.
This isn't recommended and maybe there's a conflict with you're CSS.
Try to set height and width value in your CSS file.